# URL issue with AWS load balancer and SSL certificate

Tags: urls

I recently installed Civicrm on AWS. App works great! However, when I creat a load balancer with a SSL certificate and point the Domain towards the LB, I get a 503 page. If I don't use SSL, everything works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you are going to find the answer you want on this stack. I would suggest posting to https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should look at log the load balancer. the 503 might be generated there (ie. the LB can't reach the backend) or it might be that the LB can reach the real servers hosting civi, but they can't process the request

Assuming you trust amazon (a big assumption), you might want to say that the https LB can talk to an unsecure civi server (via http).

Otherwise if you want to be more secure and don't trust amazon, you might need to configure your civicrm server so they handle https too.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing more about your configuration - but the first thing to check is that your BASE_URL setting in `civicrm.settings.php` is set to HTTPS.

Besides that, I'd check the web server logs (Apache/nginx/etc.) on the CiviCRM host.  It's pretty common to get a 503 from a reverse proxy when it can't connect to the backend server.  Troubleshooting that is out of scope for this Stack Exchange, but it will tell you whether this problem is CiviCRM-specific or not.